# Find & Replace PHP Short Tags in Visual Studio Code 1.26.1

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find and replace php short tags over an old legacy php project in all files.

Apparently I cant figure out the regex expression by myself.

I want to find all occurrences of `<?` but not `<?php` and replace them with `<?php`.

I have tried this `/<?\($\|[^p]\)` but its not finding any results.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a find on this pattern:

```
<\?(?!php)
```

And then replace with:

```
<?php
```

This answer assumes that there would not be things like `<?blah` in your source code, or, if there were, that the replacement `<?phpblah` would be acceptable to you.

Comment: That first `?` needs to be escaped: `<\?(?!php)`

Comment: The first suggestion `<?(?!php)` tells me _Expression matches everything._ and the second `<\?(?!php)` tells me _Error parsing regex near '<\?(?!php)' at character offset 5: Unrecognized flag: '!'. (Allowed flags: i, m, s, U, u, x.)_.

Comment: Ok I have found that I need to add `"search.useRipgrep": false` to my settings in VS Code.
Then the second suggestion works. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad we sorted this out eventually.

Comment: `"search.usePCRE2": true` is what you want in your settings.  I don't believe `"search.useRipgrep": false` is supprted anymore.

Comment: Yeah, `"search.useRipgrep": false` is deprecated.

Comment: you made my day , thanks